# PHP MYSQL Date format outputs zero

Tags: php, mysql, variables, date

This variable gets inserted into my `mysql` database:

```
$n_date = date('d-m-Y');
```

and in the database i always see this:

`0000-00-00 00:00:00`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `NOW()` within your SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your format is wrong. MySQL expects the date to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. So:

```
$n_date = date('d-m-Y');
```

should be

```
$n_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Or, for completeness:

```
$n_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to format dates for insert into MySQL as yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

Your format is incorrect. Why not just `INSERT` `NOW()`?

```
INSERT INTO tbl (dateCol) VALUES (NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$n_date = date('YYYY-mm-dd hh:ii:ss');
```

Insert that way.